# Create new window and insert dynamic content in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm having trouble creating a new window and adding content from my extension. Since I can't call window.open from my script without losing a reference to my new window, I'm forced to use chrome.windows.create.

Essentially what I want is this:

```
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.document.writeln( 'hello world' );
```

To create the equivalent in my chrome extension, i'm trying this:

```
chrome.windows.create({ type: 'popup' } , function(newWindow) {
                newWindow.tabs[0].executeScript(null, { code: 'document.write("hello world");' })
            });
```

The new window is created, however I can't seem to access the document object of the newly created window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problems in your code

- If you create a new window without any `URL`, it will create two windows with `chrome://newtab` and a `blank popup window`.
- You have to use chrome.tabs.executeScript with correct parameters not `newWindow.tabs[0].executeScript`

## Working Version

```
chrome.windows.create({
    type: 'popup',
    url: "https://www.google.co.in/"
}, function (newWindow) {
    console.log(newWindow);
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(newWindow.tabs[0].id, {
        code: 'document.write("hello world");'
    });
});
```

Comment: You sir, are awesome. Thank You! 

Is there a way to open a blank window ? I tried using 'about:blank' but that doesn't work.

Comment: @OmarStewey: It is not possible till date.

Comment: @OmarStewey @Sudarshan, you could open a window with the just `<html><body></body></html>` in it.

Comment: Is it possible to use a url in the extension to create the window, i.e. url: "local.html"? When I try I get a permissions error, "Extension manifest must request permission to access this host."